# "[xX][mM][lL]" is not allowed. - creating XSLT file within String

Tags: java, xml, xslt, saxon

I know there was a lot of these in this forum but none of the answers solved my problem.

I have a class that dynamically generates xslt file (don't ask why, I have lot of webservice responses to process and I found XSLT as the fastest way to do it and I do not want to create xslt file for every single webservice response).

So I am creating my XSLT in class XSLT writer using string builder, I get correct output

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:wd="urn:com.workday/bsvc"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" exclude-result-prefixes="xs" version="2.0">
    <xsl:output method="text" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:variable name="singleQ">
        <xsl:text>'</xsl:text>
    </xsl:variable>
    <xsl:variable name="doubleQ">
        <xsl:text>''</xsl:text>
    </xsl:variable>
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <file>
            <xsl:for-each select="wd:Get_Frequencies_Response/wd:Response_Data/wd:Frequency">
                <xsl:text>{'</xsl:text>
                <xsl:value-of
                    select="replace(wd:Frequency_Data/wd:Annualization_Factor, $singleQ, $doubleQ)"/>
                <xsl:text>','</xsl:text>
                <xsl:value-of
                    select="replace(wd:Frequency_Data/wd:Frequency_Behavior_Reference, $singleQ, $doubleQ)"/>
                <xsl:text>','</xsl:text>
                <xsl:value-of
                    select="replace(wd:Frequency_Data/wd:Frequency_ID, $singleQ, $doubleQ)"/>
                <xsl:text>','</xsl:text>
                <xsl:value-of select="replace(wd:Frequency_Data/wd:Name, $singleQ, $doubleQ)"/>
                <xsl:text>','</xsl:text>
                <xsl:value-of
                    select="replace(wd:Frequency_Data/wd:Use_Weekly_Hours, $singleQ, $doubleQ)"/>
                <xsl:text>','</xsl:text>
                <xsl:value-of
                    select="replace(wd:Frequency_Data/wd:Used_in_Payroll_Interface, $singleQ, $doubleQ)"/>
                <xsl:text>'},</xsl:text>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </file>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I know that this one is correct because I paste it into Oxygen xml and format it and ^ this is what I get. (Originally XSLT is written in ONE line, so I format it in Oxygen just to check if the output is OK).

Then I use this method to create my transformer:

```
    private Transformer createTransformer(XSLTWriter xslt) throws Exception {
    Transformer transformer = null;
    TransformerFactory tf = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
    Source s = new StreamSource(new StringReader(xslt.getXSLT()));
    transformer = tf.newTransformer(s);
    return transformer;
}
```

And I get an error for the XSLT I have pasted above :

```
    11:16:24,432 ERROR [stderr] (Get Frequencies) Error on line 1 column 1276
11:16:24,433 ERROR [stderr] (Get Frequencies)   SXXP0003: Error reported by XML parser: The processing instruction target matching
11:16:24,434 ERROR [stderr] (Get Frequencies)   "[xX][mM][lL]" is not allowed.
11:16:24,435 ERROR [stderr] (Get Frequencies) javax.xml.transform.TransformerConfigurationException: Failed to compile stylesheet. 1 error detected.
11:16:24,436 ERROR [stderr] (Get Frequencies)   at net.sf.saxon.PreparedStylesheet.prepare(PreparedStylesheet.java:140)
11:16:24,437 ERROR [stderr] (Get Frequencies)   at net.sf.saxon.TransformerFactoryImpl.newTemplates(TransformerFactoryImpl.java:135)
11:16:24,438 ERROR [stderr] (Get Frequencies)   at net.sf.saxon.TransformerFactoryImpl.newTransformer(TransformerFactoryImpl.java:86)
11:16:24,439 ERROR [stderr] (Get Frequencies)   at __redirected.__TransformerFactory.newTransformer(__TransformerFactory.java:132)
11:16:24,440 ERROR [stderr] (Get Frequencies)   at config.loader.ConfigLoader.createTransformer(ConfigLoader.java:235)
11:16:24,440 ERROR [stderr] (Get Frequencies)   at config.loader.ConfigLoader.run(ConfigLoader.java:102)
11:16:24,442 ERROR [stderr] (Get Frequencies)   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Has anyone ever done that?

Comment: At which place is the error reported? The error message refers to the unformatted XSLT, the XSLT is formatted.

Comment: so should I add \n ? to every single line?

Comment: Either that, or just write where in the formatted String is the text found at column 1276 in the unformatted String.

Comment: Btw. your pasted XSLT is not complete anyway. You miss at least the closing `xsl:stylesheet` tag

Comment: there is no column 1276, when I copy the XSLT into notepad++ i have only 1271 columns, .trim() didnt help

Comment: Well, then maybe my comment from above is already the solution? Did you simply forget the closing `xsl:stylesheet` tag and the error message is simply misleading? If this is the case, I'll make my commen an answer for you to upvote and accept. I assumed you just forgot to copy it over here.

Comment: your assumption is correct, i have pasted it uncarefuly. I have edited the post.

Comment: Can you please post the unmanipulated output of `System.out.println(xslt.getXSLT())`?

Comment: Incidentally, you don't need to be defensive about generating XSLT stylesheets programmatically. It's often a very elegant solution. That's one of the benefits of XSLT being written in XML syntax. Generally though I would generate the XSLT as a tree, not as lexical XML.

Answer (score 2):

The error message makes it clear there is a processing instruction (or XML declaration) of the form `<?xml ....?>` at position 1276 in the source stylesheet you are supplying. This isn't allowed (if it's an XML declaration it must be at the start, if it's a processing instruction then it mustn't be called "xml").

Now the input you've shown doesn't contain this, so we have to conclude that the input you have shows us isn't the input that you are actually processing.

The fact that the input you've shown doesn't include an end tag for the `xsl:stylesheet` element might be a clue.

Comment: Many thanks for Saxon. :-) But I think you are wrong here. If you follow the comments, you see that there is no position 1276. Could my assumption be correct, that simply the closing `stylesheet` tag is missing and the error message is just misleading?

Comment: just like in comment above, I have pasted it uncarefully, post edited - every tag is in there, xml declaration is in there. there is no position 1276 because whole string has 1271 length/cols

Comment: @mat_zat what is "your whole string"? What you're showing is an XSLT file, not a string. Show, and therefore watch unbiased, your code unmodified, and you'll find the problem before we can point it out to you.

Comment: @kumesana string as an xslt code without indentination

Comment: @Vampire anything is possible but it seems highly unlikely that Xerces would report a problem with `<?xml` at position 1276 if there is no `<?xml` and no position 1276. My next diagnostic would be to do `System.err.println(xslt.getXSLT())` or perhaps `System.err.println(xslt.getXSLT().substring(1250))`

Comment: @mat_zat I was serious: don't say, show. It's always irrational to say things you could have shown instead.

Comment: Yep, in the meantime he at least confirmed that the post here was erroneous. Sounds like the XSLT is duplicated in the string or something like that.

Comment: @kumesana      I have printed out the result to .dat file and apparently there is a char I do not recognize before the xml declaration ö<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>. How can I get rid of this? I have never inserted it in my code.

Comment: @mat_zat it is a frequent practice to start an XML file with a character called "zero-width non breaking space". It's not obvious when it's there because it is invisible and takes up no space (hence zero-width). Therefore it can be annoying to try and detect it, as well as removing it. XML is designed to accept starting with it flawlessly, however its presence can be screwed up through the toolchain if some component doesn't handle non-ascii charsets correctly, which can ultimately result in a ö in its place. I'd suggest analyzing a hex dump of your source code to look for this invisible char.

Comment: If "there is no position 1276 because whole string has 1271 length/cols" and your parser is reporting the character sequence '<?xml' at position 1276, it seems possible that some string beginning `<?xml` is being appended to your string, or read by the parser after it finishes with your string.